# PHP Form Validation

Tags: php, validation, arrays, field

This question will undoubtedly be difficult to answer and ask in a way that makes sense but I'll try my best:

I have a form which uses PHP to display certain sections of the form such as:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['EnrType'] == "Individual") { display only form information for individual enrollment } ?>
```

and

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['Num_Enrs'] > 6) { display only form information for 7 total members enrollment } ?>
```

In each form piece, unique information is collected about each enrollee but the basic criteria for each enrollee is the same, i.e. All enrollee's must use have a value in the FirstName field. Each field is named according to the enrollee number, i.e. Num1FirstName; Num2FirstName.

I have a PHP validation script which is absolutely fantastic and am not looking to change it but the issue I am running into is duplication of the script in order to validate ALL fields in one swoop.

On submission, all POSTED items are run through my validation script and based on the rules set return an error if they do not equal true.

Sample code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  // import the validation library
  require("validation.php");

  $rules = array(); // stores the validation rules

  //All Enrollee Rules
  $rules[] = "required,Num1FirstName,Num2FirstName,The First Name field is required.";
```

The script above does the following, $rules[] ="REQUIREMENT,fieldname,error message"
where requirement gives criteria (in this case, simply that a value is passed), fieldname is the name of the field being validated, and error message returns the error used.

My Goal is to use the same formula above and have $rules[] run through ALL firstnames and return the error posted ONLY if they exist (i.e. dont check for member #7's first name if it doesnt exist on the screen).

If I simply put a comma between the 'fieldnames' this only checks for the first, then second, and so on so this wont work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not gonna lie. This is tough to understand. You might want to reword parts of this or add even more detail to make it more clear.

Comment: Another way of doing this, which may help me out would be to run validation through Javascript (yes I know it can be turned off but will give me clear way to process in php).

Let's assume I have 20 FirstName fields (titled FirstName1, FirstName2, FirstName3, etc).

My javascript to ensure 'something' was passed during POST is:
if (theForm.FirstName1.value == "")
{
alert("Please enter your First Name.");
theForm.FirstName1.focus();
return (false);
}

Is there any way to run through ALL FirstNames, alert() if error is found on specific fields (preferred one box), then focus the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly:

**1. Define types**
First, you need to define what type of field requires what kinds of rules, e.g.:
`$type['FirstName']['requirement'] = 'required';
$type['FirstName']['error_message'] = 'The First Name field is required.';

// just random example:
$type['MobilePhone']['requirement'] = 'optional';
$type['MobilePhone']['error_message'] = 'Only enter digits.';`

**2. Go through each posted value**
Second, check for each posted value what type of field it is. Now a lot of stuff might be included in the `$_POST` array, and you only need to check certain fields. It might make it a lot easier to use names like `checkthis;1234;FirstName` for your input fields.
`foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  // split the key, so you know what's what:
  $data = explode(';',$key);

  // now $data[0] tells you what kind of field it is
  // $data[1] is the ID of the enrollee (your Num1, Num2)
  // $data[2] is the type of field

  // only do checks for posted fields that start with "checkthis"
  if ($data[0]=='checkthis') {
    // now you can fill the $rule array:
    $rule[] = $type[$data[2]]['requirement'] . ',' . $key . ',' . $type[$data[2]]['error_message'];
  }
}`
This way it doesn't matter what you include in your form. As long as you've defined the type of field, a rule will be added to the rule array if it's included in the $_POST values, and your validation script will do the rest.

---

**Edit**
If you structure your input fields like this:

```
<input type="text" name="F1Firstname" value="" />
<input type="text" name="F2Firstname" value="" />
etc..
```

..and you submit the form, the $_POST array will e.g. look like this:

```
//print_r($_POST) gives:

Array
(
    [F1FirstName] => John
    [F2FirstName] => Jane
)
```

..the easiest thing to do is to loop through each of those with `foreach`:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  // first $key will be "F1FirstName"
  // first $value will be "John"

  // second $key will be "F2FirstName"
  // second $value will be "Jane"

  // etc
}
```

Now, in that $_POST will also be other types of fields, like e.g. `F1MobilePhone` or whatever, that require different validations and different messages. So for each of those fields, you need to find out what type it is, to determine what kind of message to enter into your validation function. One option would be (this goes within the `foreach` statement):

```
if (strstr($key,'FirstName')) {
  // add a validation rule for the FirstName type
}
if (strstr($key,'Somethingelse')) {
  // etc
}
```

I don't know how your validation script works, but I'm guessing you're doing something like this:

```
// import the validation library
require("validation.php");

$rules = array(); // stores the validation rules

// All Enrollee Rules
$rules[] = "required,Num1FirstName,The First Name field is required.";

// Call on the validation function
$result = validate($rules);
```

Then you'll probably receive back whether, in this case, "Num1FirstName" was valid or not. Since you use an array `$rules`, the validator can probably handle multiple lines at once. Simply add more values to the array, but don't add another variable. If you do this:

```
$rules[] = "required,Num1FirstName,Num2FirstName,The First Name field is required.";
```

..the validator will think that the "Num2FirstName" is the error message, since that's the 3rd value you enter, and it won't know what to do with the actual message which is now 4th value. Try this instead:

```
$rules[] = "required,Num1FirstName,The First Name field is required.";
$rules[] = "required,Num2FirstName,The First Name field is required.";
```

So bringing that all together gives you this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  // first $key will be "F1FirstName"
  // first $value will be "John"

  // second $key will be "F2FirstName"
  // second $value will be "Jane"

  if (strstr($key,'FirstName')) {
    $rules[] = "required,$key,The First Name field is required.";
  }
  if (strstr($key,'Somethingelse')) {
    $rules[] = "required,$key,Some other message for this type of field.";
  }
}

// call on your validate function and feed it the $rules array you've created
```

Adding JavaScript to (pre-)validate is a whole different story. In the end you still need to validate it in PHP because, like you said, the JS check can easily be bypassed. So I guess fixing this first might be best.

Comment: @Alec - I think you are probably on the right track. I am having a bit of a hard time following but will try this. I think based on what you describe though i still have to create custom error messages for all first name types. The fields are defined as F1FirstName and F2FirstName currently. I may have to simply build out a TON of code to have this checked. Thank you!

Comment: What is "F1" and "F2" exactly? If they're both of the type "firstname", and both should return the same error message when they don't pass your validation, just make sure that you find out what type of field it is. Not too pretty but certainly possible: `if (strstr($fieldname,'FirstName')) { // do a firstname validation }`.

Comment: F1 and F2 are indicators for which athlete the FirstName belongs to and 'must' be attached to the field name.  i'm not sure how to separate F1 from Firstname, then validate, then put them back together in the end. Perhaps you can assist with the javascript bit i put in my comment below the original post. I think this will help me discover the right answer.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a few things. Posting how that validator works might clear a few things up if it still doesn't work as you intended.

Comment: Alec - I think it does but ultimately adding the second line (as you mentioned) is exactly what I am trying to avoid. In one form I have over 200 variables so listing the rules line by line 200 times is what I was trying to avoid but just may be what I am forced to do!

Comment: Why avoid it? Isn't that exactly what the validator requires?

Comment: I want to avoid it because I then have to create hundreds of line of code when the goal of my original post was to consolidate the code. The answer you gave is exactly what I am already doing.

Comment: Then I don't really get what you're trying to do :) If you have a page with say 100 people and thus possibly 100 first names, and you want to check each name for its validity after an update, you'll need to check each of those 100 names one way or the other. Either call on the validator 100 times, or change the validator in such a way that it'll accept an array (so you only have to call it once) and it returns an array with the fields that didn't pass the validation.

Comment: @Alec - reviewing this again, you have been a great help!