# PHPMailer sending emails too early

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have the following code which I need help with.  I got this snippet from PHPMailer examples:

```
//Send the message, check for errors
if(!$mail->Send()) {

    die ("Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo);

} else {

    echo "Message sent!";

}
```

If the `if` is true, it seems to send the email on the actual first line of the `if` statement.  Is this correct?

If that is correct, how do I check if everything is OK, as in, all the email details are valid, run the `else`, which will do some database entry stuff, and then send the email.

Is that possible?

---

**UPDATE:**

The following seems to work:

```
if($mail->ErrorInfo) {

    echo "some error happened";

} else {

    echo "email details are ok<br />";
    echo "do database entry stuff<br />";
    echo "if new record exists, send email";
// if (db entry was successful) {
        $mail->Send();
// } else {
    echo "email not sent, something wrong at db entry stage";
// }

}
```

Can anyone see any issues with using this method?

Comment: You do all that before this.

Comment: So, do your check, insert into db then run this...

Comment: @relentless That's his question: how does he check whether the parameters are valid without actually sending?

Comment: @relentless, basically, I want to do the check to make sure the mail details are all good, do the database entry stuff, and then if the database entry stuff is ok, only then send the email.

Comment: @oshirowanen Just wondering, is there any reason you are wasting the resources to check a negative on the 'if' line instead of the 'else' line? Seems like a wasted bit to check 'if not' in the main 'if' instead of the 'else'. I mean, wouldn't you want return 'null' to also be caught?

Comment: What do you mean by "mail details are all good" ?

Comment: Search around for php or javascript form validation. It's sort of hard to answer your question because i'm not sure how you have everything structured.

Comment: @JClaspill, a return of null is considered `false` unless using the value and type comparison `===`

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821316/php-form-validation

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ah, nice point. Didn't realize that. My comment still has a point though. Why do the negative like that in this scenario? Is there some reason I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Please see update to question.

Comment: will `ErrorInfo` have something useful in it before calling `send()`? The `ErrorInfo` May be for `send()` errors?

Comment: @DanJAB, I don't know to be honest.  This is the first time I'm using PHPMailer and I don't know how detailed the `ErrorInfo` gets and I don't know all possible errors it captures.

Comment: The docs here: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=properties don't say much about it either. Only that It holds the most recent error. I would try using your code and try to make it fail to see if this is the case or not. Otherwise the easiest way may be performing the database op and then rolling back on error.

Comment: @JClaspill, the way he has it is good, if there was an error he can deal with it first and just continue on with the script if there isnt one, he doesnt need the to even wrap any code in the else block as any code after the error check should assume the mail sent successfully or even if there was an error it was dealt with. If there is some error that would affect the rest of the script it should be dealt with first. Although he should be checking database stuff in the if instead of the send since his mail sending depends on successful database calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your mail depends on database entries being successful they should be checked first before even attempting mail as if the db calls arent successful there is no need to do any mail stuff at all

```
if( !$dbStuffSuccessful ) {
   //Handle db failure and leave
   die("db error");
} 
//We can assume that db entries were successfull 
//lets do the mail stuff

//Check mail stuff is valid, mailer does not have "checks" 
//like ->isValidEmail()
//so you will have to do these checks yourself
...

//Do whatever mailer stuff
$mailer->AddAddress($blah,$blah);
...

//Now try to send, send it seems is the only one that 
//triggers any errors so attempt and see if there is 
//an error
if(!$mail->send()) {
   //Whatever error happened will be in ->ErrorInfo 
   //Rollback db stuff and leave
   $db->dorollback();
   die('mail unsuccessful, db rolledback, mail error: '.
        print_r($mail->ErrorInfo,true));
}

//Ok we can assume no errors in db and no errors with mailer
//finish whatever else we need to do
```

Answer (score 0):

If the mail was not able to be sent, the $mail->send() line will return false - the above should work perfectly.

Comment: It works, but I want to change the sequence.  The sequence I need is this: 1. check that the email can be sent but don't send it yet.  2. do database entry stuff.  3. if new record was created in db successfully, send the email.

Answer (score 0):

The code You have shown will work, if you want to do the database edits before the email then put the database code before the code you have shown. If the email doesn't work you can then roll back the database changes with code just before the die statement.

That's how I would do it.

```
//Update database here

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    //email failed, rollback database changes.
    die ("Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo);

} else {
    //everything's fine.
    echo "Message sent!";

}
```

If it's SQL you can probably even use the `transaction` and `rollback` features